# json_decode returning blank

Tags: php, json

I am working on `facebook app`. I have stored some values in database in json format.

When I am fetching the value on the target page and trying to display the value as follow :

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `beforepublish` where `tabid` = '$page_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$contest_id = $sql['contestid'];
$temp_id = $sql["tempid"];
$value = $sql["values"];
$returnValue = json_decode($value);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnValue);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here the value of

`$value = {"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab "}`

and I am getting `$returnValue` as blank.

but When I try :

```
$returnValue = json_decode('{"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab "}');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnValue);
echo "</pre>";
```

then $returnValue is returning :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [image] => upload_1182341221.jpg
    [conttxt] => Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab 
)
```

So guys, please help me, Why I am getting a blank value in the previous case ?

**Edit**

vardump($value) is returning :

```
string '{"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab
    "}' (length=86)
```

Comment: `var_dump($value)`. What *exactly* does it look like?

Comment: Maybe what's coming from DB is blank or malformed?

Comment: var_dump($value) is returning : string '{"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab
 "}' (length=86)

Comment: what field is it stored in? text? what encoding? edit: json_decode works only with utf-8

Comment: @mc_fish in text with latin1_swedish_ci encoding

Comment: Try calling `var_dump(json_last_error_msg())` after the `json_decode()`.

Comment: @mc_fish Since that string contains only ASCII characters, it doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast undefined function but echo json_last_error(); returning 4

Comment: Is that a literal line break in the JSON string? If so that's invalid JSON. Or is it just a formatting thing?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: `4` is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` so that json string you're passing is invalid.

Comment: @deceze Yeah thanks, there was a line break in the JSON string, removed it and now it works ...

Comment: oh must be...did u ever see the source of the service_json? it is true that the ascii code should pass...but if u notice a blank space at the end of the json...could be a 2bit char...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string '{"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab
    "}' (length=86)
```

There is your problem. That linebreak and tab. It should look like:

```
string '{"image":"upload_1182341221.jpg","conttxt":"Get a chance to win Samsung Galaxy Tab"}' (length=84)
```

This is why `var_dump()` outputs the length, so you can validate against any unwanted/invisible characters.

---

You can store line breaks in javascript strings as `\n`.
`json_encode()` will do this automatically.

This applies for all escape sequences (commonly used ones are `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\b`).

Comment: If sometime I need to store such values in `conttxt` that has some line break then how can I store them ?

Comment: @lord_linus I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit weird but it may have to do with the database not giving you UTF8 strings (which json_decode needs).

Try

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
```

before your actual query.

//edit:
The linebreak is actually causing the problem. try with the json validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

try to get it in utf8.

From the json_decode doc ( This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data. )